# Does Python PIL support converting jpg to webp with all support that cwebp has?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, webp

I am converting jpg to webp format using cwebp tool provided in official doc.
I am checking if PIL library supports converting images from jpg to webp with all the support cwebp CLI has? like  -lossless or quality -q.

I am asking this because I didn't see any documentation for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation does clearly say that the `save` method for WebP files supports the `quality` parameter.  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried with cwebp library vs quality parameter, former has size of 100KB and latter has size of 178KB for the same image. That made me think that.